# Java EE application deployment issue

Tags: java, tomcat8, eclipse-jee

I try to deploy my JEE application with tomcat, I can deploy the war file but I can just access to the home page, the other URL doesn't work. It's working without problem in Eclipse.

For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/DendrisDeasesApps/upload-multiple
```

it's responding in eclipse but not after tomcat deployment

But this url its working both in eclipse and after tomcat deployment:

```
http://localhost:8080/DendrisDeasesApps/loginok
```

The application was importing from existing war file and I did a lot of modifications
Maybe I have to change web.xml file ?

tomcat conf `server.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


  
    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />            
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Catalina logs :

```
29-Dec-2020 17:52:10.716 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
29-Dec-2020 17:52:10.718 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 6855 ms
```

My eclipse log (working well in eclipse) :

```
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DendrisDiagnosisApps' did not find a matching property.
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server built:          Feb 2 2016 19:34:53 UTC
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server number:         8.0.32.0
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: OS Name:               Windows 10
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: OS Version:            10.0
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Architecture:          amd64
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: JVM Version:           1.8.0_261-b12
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFOS: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_261/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_261/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_261/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\mathilde\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\mathilde\Documents\eclipse;;.
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFOS: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFOS: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFOS: Initialization processed in 882 ms
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFOS: Démarrage du service Catalina
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFOS: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:48 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFOS: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Dec 30 11:32:48 CET 2020]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
WARN : org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass - composite-id class does not override hashCode(): eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.entities.GprnormalizeddataId
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3f6dd930: defining beans [filterMultipartResolver,dao,daoEnv,daoDiseases,daoOrganisme,daoRole,daoUtilRole,daoUtilisateurs,daoDossiers,daoMethodologies,daoApplicationSetUp,metier,daoDossier,daoSouches,daoHeader,daoRawData,daoNormData,daoResult,daoResFlag,daoRpackage,daoRunningConf,daoRconfpackage,daoUtilisateur,daoEnvironment,daoTypeprelevent,daoDeletedFile,dataSource,persistenceUnitManager,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,requestDataValueProcessor,org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,encoder,customUserDetailsService,userDetailsDao,authenticationProvider,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3135 ms
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed Dec 30 11:32:51 CET 2020]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@27ea8671: defining beans [mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,servicesDAOUploadImpl,userDetailsDaoImpl,diseasesHomeBis,gprheaderdataHome,gprnormalizeddataHome,scopedTarget.measurementsDataRequest,measurementsDataRequest,organismesHomeBis,scopedTarget.userDataSession,userDataSession,utilisateursHomeBis,exceptionHandlingController,fileUploadController,globalExceptionController,homeController,mainController,userDataManager,fileUploadValidator,traitementInputFileImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping#0,messageSource,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#2,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#2,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3f6dd930
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/upload-single],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.upload(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/singleSearch],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.singleSearchResult(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/downloadMultipleResultPDF],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public void eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.downloadMultipleResultPDF(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/validate-selection],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.selectionValidation(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/validateMultiResult],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public void eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.validateMultiResult(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/displayMultipleSearch],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.displayMultipleSearch(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/afficheDossierDiscordant],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.afficherDossierDiscordant(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.Integer)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/downloadResultPDF],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public void eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.downloadResultPDF(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/cancel-selection || /backToList],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.cancelSelectedFileValidation(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/uploadsingle],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.uploadFileHandler(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.model.FileUpload,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult) throws eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.exception.DuplicateDBEntry
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/multipleSearch],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.multipleSearchResult(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/uploadmultiple],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.uploadFileHandler_multiple(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.model.FileUpload,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult) throws eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.exception.DuplicateDBEntry
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/adminTasks],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.searchFilesToPurge(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/searchResults],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.searchResults(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/purgeSearch],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.purgeFiles(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/validateResult],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public void eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.validateResult(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/afficheDossier],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.afficherDossier(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/validateselectedfile],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.ValiderDossier(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/downloadPDF],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public void eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.downloadPDF(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/upload-multiple],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.upload_multiple(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/download/{type}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public void eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.FileUploadController.downloadFile(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/labSetUpFormAction],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView eu.ippon.DendrisDiseasesApps.MainController.createLabSetUp()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in globalExceptionController
Bean MeasurmentData Session
BeanUserData Session
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/exceptionhandling] onto handler 'exceptionHandlingController'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/exceptionhandling/*] onto handler 'exceptionHandlingController'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/fileupload] onto handler 'fileUploadController'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/fileupload/*] onto handler 'fileUploadController'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/home] onto handler 'homeController'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/home/*] onto handler 'homeController'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/main] onto handler 'mainController'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/main/*] onto handler 'mainController'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/css/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/images/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#2'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 1263 ms
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
déc. 30, 2020 11:32:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFOS: Server startup in 7383 ms
```

I have no idea what is the problem, i can't acces URL by my menu and when I enter directly URL i have timing out message.

Comment: Can you add details on how tomcat and apache are setup?  URL issues like this may depend on the apache and tomcat rewrite and proxy rules.

Comment: When you say "not responding," what do you mean?  Is it timing out?  Do you see an error message?  Also, you've defined a `UserDatabaseRealm` in your deployment file.  Are you using the same database for users and passwords?

Comment: Are there any errors in `logs/catalina.out`?

Comment: yes it's timing out "Time out Session"

Comment: Yes I am using the same database for users and passwords. I have no idea what is the problem, i can't acces URL by my menu and when I enter directly URL i have timing out message. The version before application modification is working